# Interdependent implicits and their use with type families

Tags: scala, implicit, type-families

I am trying to put a [type family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_family) imitation to use in a pattern where a typeclass instance depends on a type resolved by another typeclass instance, which is presented in the following block:

```
( implicit someTypeResolver: SomeTypeResolver[ a ],
           stringRep: StringRep[ someTypeResolver.SomeType ] )
```

where you can see the `stringRep` resolution being dependant on the resolution of `someTypeResolver`.

Here's the complete source

```
// A typeclass, 
// which is basically just a type-function from type `a` to `SomeType`
trait SomeTypeResolver[ a ] {
  type SomeType
}
object SomeTypeResolver {
  // An instance, which maps type `Int` to `Boolean`
  implicit val int = new SomeTypeResolver[ Int ]{ type SomeType = Boolean }
  // An instance, which maps type `Char` to `String`
  implicit val char = new SomeTypeResolver[ Char ]{ type SomeType = String }
}

// A simple typeclass which maps a type to some string representation
trait StringRep[ a ] {
  val string: String
}
object StringRep {
  implicit val boolean = new StringRep[ Boolean ]{ val string = "I'm a bool" }
  implicit val char = new StringRep[ Char ]{ val string = "I'm a char" }
}

// Having the following function, which is supposed to return a string 
// representation of a type, which `a` is mapped to
def resolve
  [ a ]
  ( implicit someTypeResolver: SomeTypeResolver[ a ],
             stringRep: StringRep[ someTypeResolver.SomeType ] )
  = stringRep.string

// I expect it to behave like so
assert( resolve[ Int ] == "I'm a bool" )
assert( resolve[ Char ] == "I'm a char" )
```

But the above fails to compile with the following message:

> illegal dependent method type: parameter appears in the type of another parameter in the same section or an earlier one

How to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

So, as the error states, we need to somehow move the `stringRep` resolution into another postponed section. To achieve this we can instantiate an intermediate object, which introduces this section in its `apply` function:

```
def resolve
  [ a ]
  ( implicit someTypeResolver: SomeTypeResolver[ a ] )
  = 
  new {
    def apply( implicit stringRep: StringRep[ someTypeResolver.SomeType ] ) =
      stringRep.string
  }

assert( resolve[ Int ].apply == "I'm a bool" )
assert( resolve[ Char ].apply == "I'm a string" )
```

It must be noted that with this approach, the user must explicitly call the `apply` function as shown in the assertions above.